# App does not open when run scheme on Chrome/Firefox

Tags: android

I want to start my Android app by using scheme, this is my code:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.myapp.SplashScreenActivity"
        android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:noHistory="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="www.myhost.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/company/"
                android:scheme="http" />
            <data
                android:host="myhost.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/company/"
                android:scheme="http" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Then run : myhost.com/company/ on browsers and results:

- Default internet browser: App open normally
- Chrome: does not work
- Firefox: does not work.

I don't know how to solve it, please help me and explain me about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use "http" as the scheme, because Chrome and Firefox can handle this kind of URL they will not call other app to handle it. Instead, you can use a self-defined scheme such as "myprotocol" which can not be handled by those browser, they will call your app to handle it. You can run "myprotocol://myhost.com/company/" on Chrome to test it.